# Как распаковать переменные из строки используя шаблон

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, шаблоны

Есть патерн:

```
pattern = 'Тесттест констант текст {0-9.}*% текст текст {0-9.}* to {0-9.}*'
```

И набор строк по типу:

```
strings['1'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 120% текст текст 3423 to 6754'
strings['2'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 56% текст текст 12 to 34'
strings['3'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 0% текст текст 345 to 423'
strings['4'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 3% текст текст 34 to 45'
```

Строки и патерны естественно могут отличатся, программа определяет соответствие строки патерну путем re.fullmatch(pattern, string). Собственно сабж в том чтобы распаковать переменные в список.
Как сделать это для конкретного шаблона я конечно понимаю, но таких шаблонов тысячи, есть-ли какая-то библиотека позволяющая просто распарсить переменные в список.

---

Вот моя текущая костыльная реализация.

```
import re

AffixList = {
    1:
        {
        'pattern': 'Area contains [0-9.]*% increased number of Remnants',
        'tag': 'PERCENT',
        'crutchs': ['Area contains ', '% increased number of Remnants']
        },
    2:
        {
        'pattern': 'Area contain [0-9]* to [0-9]* additional Chests Markers',
        'tag': '2FLAT',
        'crutchs': ['Area contain ', ' to ', ' additional Chests Markers']
        },
    }

def GetAffixVal(str):
    for k in AffixList:
        affix = AffixList[k]
        if re.fullmatch(affix['pattern'], str):
            for c in affix['crutchs']:
                str = re.sub(c, " ", str)

            vars = []
            list = re.split(" ", str)
            for var in list:
                if var != '':
                    vars.append(float(var))
            return (k, affix['tag'], vars)
    return None


AfixData = GetAffixVal("Area contain 3456 to 34567 additional Chests Markers")
print(AfixData)
```

Собственно функция возвращает кортеж (2, '2FLAT', [3456.0, 34567.0]) что мне и нужно. Суть в том чтобы сделать это проще без необходимости прописывания кучи кусков строк между которыми висят переменные.

Comment: *Как сделать это для конкретного шаблона я конечно понимаю* - покажите, как вы бы это делали

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Приложил свою кривую реализацию чтобы было больше понятно чего я хочу добится)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю правильно ли я тебя понял

```
import re

strings = {}
pattern = r'Тесттест констант текст (\d+)\s*% текст текст (\d+) to (\d+)'

strings['1'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 120% текст текст 3423 to 435'
strings['2'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 56% текст текст 12 to 34'
strings['3'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 0% текст текст 345 to 423'
strings['4'] = 'Тесттест констант текст 3% текст текст 34 to 45'

for i in strings:
    string = strings[i]
    s = re.fullmatch(pattern, string)
    if s != None:
        print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

Comment: не совсем re.fullmatch(pattern, string) просто возвращает всю строку целиком, мне же нужно чтобы вернуло то что было на месте \d+\s*% , \d+ , \d+

Comment: @ElixTT тогда вы можете обернуть нужные значения в скобки, это создаст группы (`pattern = r'Тесттест констант текст (\d+)\s*% текст текст (\d+) to (\d+)'`). Теперь можно вызвать `re.findall(pattern, string)`, он вернет список кортежей с совпадениями (если непонятно - попробуйте сами). Если хотите использовать метод `re.fullmatch()`, то нужно будет немного поработать с возвращенным объектом (переменная `s` в коде выше). У нее есть метод `group(num)`. Первая группа будет содержать число перед процентом, вторая и третья - другие два числа.

Comment: Спасибо это именно то что мне и было нужно)

Comment: @Rick, советую вам обновить ответ, соответствуя тому, что действительно было нужно ТС